# How to determine the distance to one point from another in a 3D coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-systems, 3d

I wonder how I can calculate the distance between two coordinates in a $3D$ coordinate-system.
Like this. I've read about *[the distance formula](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm)*:

$$d = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}$$

(How) Can I use that it $3D$ coordinates, or is there any other method?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Three_dimensions

Comment: Can I do it by just extending the distance formula, like this: $$d = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 + (z_2 - z_1)^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In three dimensions, the distance between two points (which are each triples of the form $(x, y, z))$ is given by $$d= \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2}$$

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The distance between two points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ is given by

$$d = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2+(z_2 - z_1)^2}$$

Comment: I appreciate it. Thanks ;)